# How to set background color of empty UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that currently has no data in it. I'd like to change the background color to a dark gray, but I can't seem to figure out how. I first tried setting the background color of the window in the app delegate through the following:

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:39 green:39 blue:39 alpha:1.0];
```

Then I tried setting the backgroundColor of the table view.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:39 green:39 blue:39 alpha:1.0];
```

Neither of these worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. Your problem lies in the understanding of the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[self.tbl_Name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:39.0f/255.0f green:39.0f/255.0f blue:39.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
```

**Let me know if you have problem.**

Comment: @ByronS - just try.. it will work for you :) and put your whole code of your tableView Creation ..

Comment: @ByronS, please accept this as an answer if this is useful to you.

Answer (score 7):

The reason that your code isn't working that way you want it to is because `UIColor` makes use of `float` data type values and not `int` - which are the ones you are passing.

So : `39` would be `39.0f`

To enter `RGB` values as you are trying to do - you need to add `/255.0f` as a suffix to work as the upper limit.

Also, use the `setBackgroundColor` method. Its there for a reason.

So, the correct way of going about what you are trying to do is :

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor : [UIColor colorWithRed : 39.0f/255.0f green : 39.0f/255.0f blue : 39.0f/255.0f alpha : 1.0];
```

`

Comment: Why are you repeating the same answer?

Comment: I'm not repeating. My answer is more thorough. And rather than just giving you the code - I'm actually trying to explain to you where you went wrong and what the correct way it. But I guess you don't appreciate the help.

Comment: Ok but it is so simple that it is self explaination.

Comment: You might have been able to understand it correctly. But how do I know that ? Plus, you aren't the only one who'll see this question. Someone else might see this link and then they'll be able to know where you went wrong. StackOverflow answers are not always directed to the asker. Other people can also get to know. Hence, the explanation.